# Can't send PHP mail! Form mail

Tags: php, html, email, mailto

```
    <form action="" enctype="text/plain" method="post">
    <textarea name="link" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; width: 591px;" cols="1" rows="1" placeholder="Link"></textarea>

    <textarea name="username" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; width: 591px;" cols="1" rows="1" placeholder="Username"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="send" /></form>
<div style="color: red;">*Warning</div>
- Do not submit the request more than once if you do not want duplicate items.

<?php
$to      = 'admin@bdeas.com';
$subject = 'Market Purchase';
$message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
$message2 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'])
$headers = 'From: admin@bdeas.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: admin@bdeas.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $message2, $headers);
?>
```

I have this code here but I can't seem to get this code to send the mail. I have looked at the other posts but they don't help me as I need the form details to send the mail.

EDIT! Could you tell me if there is anything wrong in the code?

Comment: What do you mean y'all missed something

Comment: so.. none of the answers worked for you below? and you're using entire code in the same page. something's gonna throw undefined index notices.

Comment: doesn't work. I have no clue why.

Comment: one reason `enctype="text/plain"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have 2 messages like that. You need to join all parts of your final message into a string. If you want to include them both, do this:

```
<?php
    $to      = 'admin@bdeas.com';
    $subject = 'Market Purchase';
    $message = $_POST['username'] . '<br />' . $_POST['name'];
    $headers = 'From: admin@bdeas.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: admin@bdeas.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: so if put that script in instead of the other php script, it should work?

Comment: I agree with @Sherif though, you probably do not need `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: so I should just use _post?

Comment: I edited my answer to remove the instances of `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: This should work as is?

Comment: Yes, have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I tried it but didn't work again. I am now thinking that it's a problem with the host I'm using. awardspace

Comment: They allow it, here is their suggested test. http://blog.awardspace.com/i-am-unable-to-use-php-mail-function-from-my-paid-hosting-account-why/

Comment: firstly, awardspace only allows using mail if you have a registered domain and pointed to their nameservers; you can't use mail "as is" from using just a free sub-domain of theirs. 2nd, look at what doesn't belong in the form tags. @JiungSong I'm surprised nobody picked up on that.

Comment: what doesn't belong in the form?

Comment: Also, I bought 1 year of hosting from them so i'm allowed.

Comment: For starters you dont need `enctype`. Also just looked at the names on your `input` tags... They are not 'username' & 'name', they are 'link' & 'username'.

Comment: yes, I know that and I have changed all of em. Removed enctype and changed username and name to link and username

Answer (score 1):

try to change,

mail($to, $subject, $message, $message2, $headers);

to

mail($to, $subject, $message.' '.$message2, $headers);

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the manual page for the `mail()` function](http://php.net//function.mail), you'll see its prototype takes 5 arguments, but they don't match what you're specifying here in your call to `mail()`.

> bool mail ( string `$to` , string `$subject` , string `$message` [, string `$additional_headers` [, string `$additional_parameters` ]] )

It looks like you're trying to send two messages at the same time, possibly? So your `$message2` argument is getting sent as the `$headers` argument that `mail()` is expecting and your actual headers is getting sent as `$additional_parameters`.

If you meant to send it all as one message body you can concatenate the two strings into one. Otherwise you can call `mail()` multiple times.

## N.B.

It's probably worth noting here that `htmlspecialchars()` doesn't help you unless you explicitly sent a `Content-type` header of `text/html` along with your email. Otherwise you're just making the message harder to read since the client will likely interpret it as `plain/text` by default.